# Python sqlite3 rowcount of update depends on Python version

Tags: python, sqlite

I am updating some rows in a `sqlite` database using the `sqlite3` package in the following `Python` code.

```
sql = """
      UPDATE
          measurements
      SET
          value=?
      WHERE
          value IS NULL
          AND counter IS NOT NULL;
      """
with self.conn:
    cur = self.conn.execute(sql, [value])
cur.rowcount
```

This runs inside a docker container. Basing its image on `Python 3.5` I get the expected row count. As soon as the image is based on `Python 3.6` the update is performed but `rowcount` is always -1. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Is the python version the only difference between your docker images, or is there a chance that the actual sqlite c lib also differs? Anyway, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount) are quite specific about the engine's support for affected rows being "quirky" :)

Comment: Pythons c lib ``_sqlite3.cpython-...`` is named differently but in both cases links against ``libsqlite3.so.0.8.6``. Well, yes maybe I should eliminate the use of ``cursor.rowcount`` as it seems unreliable.

Comment: Even though your example involves a DML statement I can't help but wonder if the statement in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions) about DDL statements no longer being auto-committed starting with python 3.6 might be relevant. Check that the `isolation_level` of the connection is the same in the two versions.

Comment: Checked the isolation level of the connection: it's an empty string in both versions. Setting it explicitly to ``None`` does not affect the cursor's ``rowcount`` attribute.